# A tag active based on area of screen in view

Tags: reactjs

I have a long scrolling webpage with multiple sections. I want the navigation bar to show which section is being viewed by changing the style of the a tag of the section in view. Is this possible?

I've made a Codepen to try and show my webpage in the it's most basic state.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQMVpG

```
class App extends Component {

  handleScroll = () => {
   //check window.Y
   //set <a href="1">1</a> to active if before <div id="2">
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <header>
     <div id="navbar" >
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#1">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#3">3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#4">4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#5">5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#6">6</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </header>
    <div id="1">
      <p>
        1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.       Mauris quis porta enim. Sed malesuada luctus velit eget porttitor. Suspendisse sit amet eros consequat, tincidunt diam sed, porttitor mi. Pellentesque sodales, massa sodales varius vulputate, diam mauris facilisis enim, sit amet scelerisque justo est ut nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ultricies eleifend porta. Nam a tincidunt mauris.       Nulla ipsum nulla, laoreet quis justo sit amet, tempus interdum quam. Duis tempus orci vitae leo facilisis fringilla. Quisque molestie ligula et nunc gravida laoreet.
      </p>
    </div>
     <div id="2">
      <p>
        2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.       Mauris quis porta enim. Sed malesuada luctus velit eget porttitor. Suspendisse sit amet eros consequat, tincidunt diam sed, porttitor mi. Pellentesque sodales, massa sodales varius vulputate, diam mauris facilisis enim, sit amet scelerisque justo est ut nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ultricies eleifend porta. Nam a tincidunt mauris.       Nulla ipsum nulla, laoreet quis justo sit amet, tempus interdum quam. Duis tempus orci vitae leo facilisis fringilla. Quisque molestie ligula et nunc gravida laoreet.
      </p>
    </div>
     <div id="3">
      <p>
        3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.       Mauris quis porta enim. Sed malesuada luctus velit eget porttitor. Suspendisse sit amet eros consequat, tincidunt diam sed, porttitor mi. Pellentesque sodales, massa sodales varius vulputate, diam mauris facilisis enim, sit amet scelerisque justo est ut nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ultricies eleifend porta. Nam a tincidunt mauris.       Nulla ipsum nulla, laoreet quis justo sit amet, tempus interdum quam. Duis tempus orci vitae leo facilisis fringilla. Quisque molestie ligula et nunc gravida laoreet.
      </p>
    </div>
     <div id="4">
      <p>
        4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.       Mauris quis porta enim. Sed malesuada luctus velit eget porttitor. Suspendisse sit amet eros consequat, tincidunt diam sed, porttitor mi. Pellentesque sodales, massa sodales varius vulputate, diam mauris facilisis enim, sit amet scelerisque justo est ut nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ultricies eleifend porta. Nam a tincidunt mauris.       Nulla ipsum nulla, laoreet quis justo sit amet, tempus interdum quam. Duis tempus orci vitae leo facilisis fringilla. Quisque molestie ligula et nunc gravida laoreet.
      </p>
    </div>
     <div id="5">
      <p>
        5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.       Mauris quis porta enim. Sed malesuada luctus velit eget porttitor. Suspendisse sit amet eros consequat, tincidunt diam sed, porttitor mi. Pellentesque sodales, massa sodales varius vulputate, diam mauris facilisis enim, sit amet scelerisque justo est ut nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ultricies eleifend porta. Nam a tincidunt mauris.       Nulla ipsum nulla, laoreet quis justo sit amet, tempus interdum quam. Duis tempus orci vitae leo facilisis fringilla. Quisque molestie ligula et nunc gravida laoreet.
      </p>
    </div>
     <div id="6">
      <p>
        6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.       Mauris quis porta enim. Sed malesuada luctus velit eget porttitor. Suspendisse sit amet eros consequat, tincidunt diam sed, porttitor mi. Pellentesque sodales, massa sodales varius vulputate, diam mauris facilisis enim, sit amet scelerisque justo est ut nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ultricies eleifend porta. Nam a tincidunt mauris.       Nulla ipsum nulla, laoreet quis justo sit amet, tempus interdum quam. Duis tempus orci vitae leo facilisis fringilla. Quisque molestie ligula et nunc gravida laoreet.
      </p>
    </div>

header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 10;
}

#navbar {
  padding-top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 2vh auto;
}

#navbar ul {
  margin: auto;
}

#navbar ul li{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: #6cfbfe;
}

#navbar a:active {
  color: #6cfbfe;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

div {
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Post your code attempts so we can help.

Comment: Have attempted to add some code so you can get an idea

Comment: Here is a working JSFiddle showing how this can be achieved. You'll just need to convert the scroll handler to work with your nav components: https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/